# How should I initialize a Mongoose connection in a Mocha unit test?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose, mocha.js

I have been looking for this all over the place. Some people seem to do

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
```

and go on with their `describe` calls. What about the async waiting, though?

```
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function (callback) {
  // yay!
});
```

How should I use this connection in Mocha tests? Should I put all my tests in the callback? Should I wrap the waiting-for-connection code in a unit test? Will the connection persist across `describe`s and `it`s?

Answer (score 7):

Mongoose [`connect`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-connect) function supports a callback.

Since Mocha asynchronous version of `before` also accepts a callback (usually called `done`), just pass it to the `connect` function, like:

```
describe("Your test", function () {

  before(function (done) {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', done);
  });
  // here you can write your tests
});
```

This way, the connection will remain active in the `describe` scope the `before` method is placed.

But, if you want to use your connection for all tests in your test file, just call it before all `describe`:

```
before(function (done) {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', done);
});

describe("first suite", function () {
  // do your tests
});

describe("second suite", function () {
  // do your tests
});

// and so on
```

Comment: Pretty much all of my tests will require this connection. Should I put all tests' `describe`s inside a big `describe` like this? I see tests that have a lot of top-level `describe`s. Will the connection persist if I make a separate `describe` after this `describe`?

Comment: Ohhh! I could do a `before` before that top-level describe instead, right? I didn't realize that I could pass in `done` like that. It makes so much sense now. Should this be a `beforeEach`?

Comment: Nope, just a `before` otherwise you're just initializing a new connection per `it`. Mongoose exports a singleton, so you do it once and each time you import a model(before of after connection) it should still share the same underlying mongodb client.

Comment: So I should be able to just move that `before` in Rodrigo's code outside the `describe` and all `describe`s will share the same client?

Comment: Actually, how do I save a reference to this connection for later use?